# Make a spaggetiplot of data

Tags: r, plot

I would like to make a spagettiplot of the data below. Treatment C should be set as the reference,1, compared to treatment A and B. Does anyone have a suggestion how to do that? Thanks in advance! :)

```
id <- rep(c(300,450), each=6)
trt <- rep(c("A","B","C"),2)
q1 <- c(100,89, 60,85,40,10)
df <- data.frame(id,trt,q1)
df
    id trt  q1
1  300   A 100
2  300   B  89
3  300   C  60
4  300   A  85
5  300   B  40
6  300   C  10
7  450   A 100
8  450   B  89
9  450   C  60
10 450   A  85
11 450   B  40
12 450   C  10
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ... ?  Have you looked at `matplot()` (will require rearranging data) or `ggplot2`?

Comment: definitely want to use a charting package. Good news is that there's tons of documentation and support for ggplot2 http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/. Otherwise, fiverr is a good site to pay somebody to make a plot like that.